# Mac OS X - rmdir fails with "Operation not permitted" for a folder created by a PC on a removable drive

Tags: macos, filesystems, virus, fat16

I have a problem (using Mac OS X 10.5.8) with the access rights of a folder that was presumably created by a virus on a disk-on-key drive when I used it with a PC. I can't remove the folder or change it's name. In Finder's Info window the Lock box is unchecked and uncheckable - if I try to check it it flips back to off.

Please see the details:

```
MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$ rmdir winamp_cache_0001/
rmdir: winamp_cache_0001/: Operation not permitted
MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$

MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$ mv winamp_cache_0001 test
mv: rename winamp_cache_0001 to test: Operation not permitted
MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$

MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$ GetFileInfo winamp_cache_0001
directory: "/Volumes/GARMIN'S/winamp_cache_0001"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 12/23/2009 14:34:52
modified: 02/13/2010 22:52:36
MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$

MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$ stat  -x winamp_cache_0001 
  File: "winamp_cache_0001"
  Size: 32768        FileType: Directory
  Mode: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)
  Uid: (  502/  maxint)
  Gid: (   20/   staff)
  Device: 14,5   Inode: 7439    Links: 1
  Access: Wed Dec 23 00:00:00 2009
  Modify: Sat Feb 13 22:52:36 2010
  Change: Sat Feb 13 22:52:36 2010
MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$

MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$ stat -r winamp_cache_0001  
234881029 7439 040777 1 502 20 0 32768 1261506600 1266081756 1266081756 1261559092 131072 64 32768 winamp_cache_0001
MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$

MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$ ls -lTd winamp_cache_0001/
drwxrwxrwx  1 maxint  staff  32768 Feb 13 22:52:36 2010 winamp_cache_0001/
MaxBookAir:GARMIN'S maxint$
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a dumb question, but what filesystem is the flash drive formatted with?  If it's NTFS and you don't have [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) installed with the NTFS-3G driver, then you can only mount NTFS drives read-only. (Unless you enable the experimental r/w NTFS support, but it seems to be very unstable so I would not recommend it).

If you're sure the disk is not mounted read-only (you can check this in Disk Utility → Info → look for "Writable"), then try deleting this directory with sudo:

```
sudo rm -r winamp_cache_0001
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install MacFUSE, just follow [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=785376) to read/write your NTFS partition, then remove the directory.

Comment: This is interesting and I had not heard of it, but given the multiple mentions of instability and filesystem corruption, I'd probably suggest sticking with NTFS-3G. See this article for references of it causing problems: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382

Comment: I tried it once and it worked.
I suggest this, because he only needs one time access to the hard drive.

Comment: The disk proved to have FAT16 filesystem, so I'm confused.

Comment: Then try with `sudo rm -rf winamp_cache_0001`.